# Target specific link with CSS

Tags: css

I need to target the middle link specifically, I want to only alter the middle link.
[image]

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's four ideas:

```
.sermons-links > :nth-child(2)

.sermons-links > a:nth-of-type(2)

.sermons-links > a[href=""]

.sermons-links > a[href="http://www.wpbuilder.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/8-Des-2019-preek.mp3"] + a
```